# TTWebController with drag refresh

Tags: objective-c, ios, refresh, three20, drag

i'm looking three20 and I wish make this thing: use a TTWebController but implement the feature that is shown on the 'Table with drag refresh', drag to the bottom and the webpage will be loaded, showing on the top the arrow like twitter, like many apps... it's possible to do this?

how can I do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull to refresh is implemented as a Table View Delegate and the TTWebController is a simple controller with a uiwebview in it.
One way around it would be to create a new TableViewController with the TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate as the table delegate. You would then create another cell with the web view.
A problem with that solution is that the web view has it's own scroll view and that will take precedence over the tableview scrollview. so you would actually need to make sure you drag the table and not the webview.
All in all I suggest you not do it :) and use a button for the refresh.